# How to get coordinates in 2D with the given points

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

I have the following coordinates:
 $[-20, -20]$, $[-20, 20]$, $[-40, 0]$, $[-40, 20]$, $[-40, 40]$,
 $[-20, 80]$, $[20, 80]$, $[40, 40]$, $[80, 20]$, $[80, -20]$.

My task is to get coordinates starting point from [0, 0].I can get the angles and the length from the above given coordinates. The angles should be between 0 to 360 positive.

Suppose I don't have the original coordinates now. I need to calculate the coordinates starting from 0,0 with angles and length.I need the current coordinate, previous and next coordinates.

Ex: if the current coordinates segment has a length of 5 then coordinates are (0,0) (0,5).The end point of the Predecessor is (0,0)and the start point of the Successor is (0,5).

What could be the formula, I need to calculate keeping in mind the quadrants??

To find the next and previous coordinates I use the formula as in quadrant 1,postive x-axis.

x1=x+l * cos(angle), y1=y+l * sin(angle).

Do the above formulas change in my case w.r.t quadrants as below or they stand the same.

x1=x-l*cos(angle), y1=y-l*sin(angle) etc (change w.r.t quadrants).
Help me find out.

Comment: Why do you have to "normalize" coordinates? What does it mean? Who asked you to do that, and what did they tell you about it?

Comment: I need to find the coordinates starting from 0,0 with the length and angle of the segments. I use x1=x+l * cos(angle), y1=y+l * sin(angle) the formula to find the coordinates. Depending on angles or quadrants (i.e 90 to 180 is quadrant II), should I change the formula by +,- combinations  @DavidK

Comment: What is exactly the angle appearing in your formulas? If it is computed starting from the positive direction of x-axis, then your formulas are fine.

Comment: I think that you misinterpret the task - I think you are asked to find the vectors that lead from the starting point (or the origin as starting point) to next point in polar representation - distance and angle. You need to look at differences and arctan functions.

Comment: @Aretino you mean x1=x+l * cos (angle) and y1=y+l * sin(angle) are fine to start from origin using these formulas to get the new coordinate points.

Comment: @Moti can you tell me what functions you are talking about more clearly.

Comment: Yes, those formula work with any angle.

Comment: @Aretino those angles indirectly mean the quadrants too, so you mean no need to do +/- of cos , sin. Always it would be positive.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/179389/find-the-new-coordinates-using-a-starting-point-a-distance-and-an-angle question is similar to this @Aretino

Comment: First find the length of a vector and than the direction based on the projections to the XY coordinates - the difference between the coordinates. In other words, two points define a vector that gets you from one point to the next one.

Comment: Can you show me small example plz @Moti

Answer (score 1):

Let take the first two points - [−20,−20], [−20,20]. The length of the vector is $\sqrt{(-20-(-20))^2+ (20-(-20))^2)}$
And tag the polar direction is $(20-(-20))/(-20-(-20))$ which goes to infinity - 90 degrees angle.

And so you go from point to point.